# How to persist the SelectedValue in a GridView when the rows are updated

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, data-binding, gridview

I have a parent GridView that is bound to an `EntityDataSource` with a child `DetailView`.
The child DetailView is bound to the parent by an `EntityDataSource`, with a ControlParameter as WhereParameter that points to the parent `GridView`.

When a user selects a row in the `GridView`, the `DetailView` is updated with the correct values.

The views are in an `UpdatePanel` and by entering a value in a `TextBox`, the user can search through records from the parent `GridView`. When a user selects a record in the parent view (say row index 1), the child is updated. But if the user starts a search now, the row on index 1 gets a different `SelectedValue`, so the `DetailView` is updated.

I want to persist the `SelectedValue` when a user selects a record.
Can I prevent the `GridView` `SelectedValue` from changing, when a user starts a search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't understood ver well, is this helping you?

> EnablePersistedSelection="true"

Enable this on GridView

Comment: Can't believe it took 4 days to get such a simple answer after all. It works perfectly. Thanks! I was searching on persisting the SelectedValue thats why I never got to the enable 'PersistedSelection' property..